# Why are the organization's Maps and Layers not visible in My Content?

Tags: arcgis-online

I'm working with a client who has an established ArcGIS Online account. They added me as an Administrator.

From the map, the Add Data button gives me access to the layers which have been configured for the organisation. But the My Content page doesn't list anything (no maps, no layers, no service definitions, etc).

Since I'm an Administrator and since I can see the layers via Add Data, shouldn't I have access to all of these items via My Content?

I can get to an individual layer's details from the map via right-click > Show Item Details. Doing so confirms that this layer is shared with the whole organisation.

Even when I choose *Allow others to export to different formats* on a layer, I can't see this layer when I use the *Add Data From ArcGIS Online* option in ArcMap. (This method works for other sites that I'm a member of.)

How can I quickly access all of the layers via My Content?

---

**Edit**: I obtained the login of another Administrator, who *can* see layers under their My Content page. The layers are listed as Shared amongst the Organization - but I still can't see them while logged in as myself.

There are also lots of Groups, so I added myself to all of them, using the other Administrator's login. Even so, I still can't see any items under My Content.

Are there any other settings which control who can access a layer via their My Contents page?

Answer (score 1):

This was user error - I misunderstood where things go in ArcGIS Online.

Because I've always been the one who creates all the layers and maps, I assumed that **My Content** is where it's all found.

In fact it's not just a clever name - it's where My Content (and only my content) goes. **Gallery** is the place I should be looking to find layers and maps created by someone else.

[image]

Comment: (I'm still horribly confused about permissions between maps and layers, depending on who created them and how they're shared.....)